# Instantaneous propagation of process covariance matrix modification's effect on state

Tags: kalman-filter

I am trying to build a zero-delay kalman filter which udates its process noise covariance matrix $Q_k$ depending on the value of the residues $z_k - H\cdot x_k$. My problem is, I have adopted a 1D constant velocity model, and the brutal change in the variance updates on the position part of state after 2 step, and not one, instantaneously as I would love it to do. (with an empty covariance matrix except for the derivative).

I have discovered ways of going around this issue, notably by predicting the covariance of state matrix as $P_{k+1|k} = F(P_{k|k}+Q_k)F^\top + Q_k$ instead of $P_{k+1|k} = FP_{k|k}F^\top + Q_k$, but that was tinkering and I am sure this has negative consequences on the optimality of the filter.

I am wondering about those consequences, and if it is possible to update instantaneously on the parameter the effect of changing the derivative's noise variance.